# Autoresizing code for HTML Websites

Tags: html, web, resize

So my teacher asked me to make a website for a school project so I did with HTML.
I hosted it on Google drive: https://6fdfc622c3b2712d089a12f8ae61231d456c2a84.googledrive.com/host/0B2OaKz7Yt-Y4YWVfdm1iWk5mMFk/Htmlcomplete.html
The website fits fine onto my laptop but when I open it on my PC it repeats itself, like the website is there but then on the sides top and bottom it has the same website over and over to fill the page.
I googled this and I tried all the solutions like setting width and height to 100% etc but it's not working.
The code is attached to this post, and please tell me what I need to add to it to make it resize to fit the resolution of different computers
Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2OaKz7Yt-Y4UUlvcjc0b1kwdHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please post a relevant sample of your code rather than simply linking to it? I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on asking [good questions]http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud When I use the code the background completely disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In you body tag use:

```
 <body style="background:url(http://i.imgur.com/o7Tiy8x.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
```

Instead of :

```
<body background:"http://i.imgur.com/o7Tiy8x.jpg">
```

It will be work.

**Suggestion:** Do not use inline **css**.You can use

```
body{background:url(http://i.imgur.com/o7Tiy8x.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;}
```

in you **css** .It's standard coding.